# How do I compare the value of an element returned by getElementsByName to a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a quiz with a text input. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check() {
                var s1 = document.getElementsByName('s1');
                if(s1 == 'ō') {
                    document.getElementById("as1").innerHTML = 'Correct';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("as1").innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
                }
                var s2 = document.getElementsByName('s2');
                if(s2 == 's') {
                    document.getElementById("as2").innerHTML = 'Correct';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("as2").innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
                }
                //(...etc...)
                var p3 = document.getElementsByName('p3');
                if(p3 == 'nt') {
                    document.getElementById("ap3").innerHTML = 'Correct';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("ap3").innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        1st sing<input type="text" name="s1"> <div id="as1"><br>
        2nd sing<input type="text" name="s2"> <div id="as2"><br>
        <!-- ...etc... -->
        3rd pl<input type="text" name="p3"> <div id="ap3"><br>
        <button onclick='check()'>Check Answers</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Every time I check answers it always says Incorrect and only shows the first question. I also need a way to clear the text fields after I check the answers. One of the answers has a macro. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize this quiz can be hacked by anyone with a browser plugin, right?

Comment: you don't even need a plugin.  just view source

Comment: In addition to the problems with `getElementsByName` you also have a logic error for your `p1` item. You probably mean `if(p1 == 'mus')`

Comment: as said you should check not to make confusion between p1 and p2 and also you should be carefull to close the tags, perhaps it is the reason why you're only displays one inputs (if I understood well your problem)

Comment: @Tom its meant as a studying tool

Comment: @sks alright, just making sure it's harmless ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getElementsByName` returns a NodeList, you can't really compare that against a string. If you have only one element with such name, you need to grab the first element from that list using such code instead:

```
var s1 = document.getElementsByName('s1')[0].value;
```

To make it more flexible and elegant plus avoid error when you have typo in a name, first add such function:

```
function SetStatus(sName, sCorrect, sPlaceholder) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(sName);
    if (elements.length == 1) {
        var placeholder = document.getElementById(sPlaceholder);
        if (placeholder) {
            var value = elements[0].value;
            placeholder.innerHTML = (value === sCorrect) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";
        } else {
            //uncomment below line to show debug info
            //alert("placeholder " + sPlaceholder+ " does not exist");
        }
    } else {
        //uncomment below line to show debug info
        //alert("element named " + sName + " does not exist or exists more than once");
    }
}
```

Then your code will become:

```
SetStatus('s1', 'ō', 'as1');
SetStatus('s2', 's', 'as2');
//...
```

Comment: Still only seeing first question after clicking button. Here is my check function: `function check()
{
SetStatus('s1', 'ō', 'as1');
SetStatus('s2', 's', 'as2');
SetStatus('s3', 't', 'as3');
SetStatus('p1', 'mus', 'ap1');
SetStatus('p2', 'tis', 'ap2');
SetStatus('p3', 'nt', 'ap3');
}`

Comment: @sks you need to close your `<div>` tags, e.g. `<div id="as1"></div>`. Your current HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName('s1')` is an array you should use `document.getElementsByName('s1')[0]` to get certain element(first in this case)

Comment: That's actually a NodeList not an array. You access it the same way, but you can't use array functions on it. (pop, push, etc)  "TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'pop'"